# jquery-2.1.4.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a master page. Master page has a header, side bar, footer comes from different UI and i can merge to use as master page.

I have mentioned

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

this jquery file is in my new UI and this is also used in my master page for sidebar functionality.

In my new UI i have used Date-picker. my date picker is not working properly when i click the date picker. I have got

```
jquery-2.1.4.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

if i am not using master page this functionality working properly. when i include this into master it returns error

> this is my side bar

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar responsive ace-save-state" ng-controller="SlideController" ng-include="'slidebar.html'">

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $(".sidebar ul li ul li").closest("li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
                    $("#Expense").addClass("active").parents(".nav li").addClass("active open");

                });
            </script>


        </div>
```

can any one help me?

Comment: how do you create this master page?

Comment: never heard of a master page

Comment: the datepicker should need additional libraries

Comment: What is the path to *jquery-2.1.4.min.js* file relatively your site root?

Comment: @madalin ivascu: for masterpage i have used 3 div in my UI this div is used to include that header footer and sidebar by using jquery.

Comment: @Alexander within my proj folder :'assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' the following path

Comment: so you are ajaxing you footer, header and sidebar? why? normally you will ajax the content not the other way around

Comment: @madalinivascu: i have updted my question. if i am not using 3 div mean, in every UI every time i should create header, footer, side bar. so that only i use this div

Comment: use php to include the header/footer/sidebar not ajax, your content is now dynamically added, your page will load the header/footer after the content is loaded which  will look kind of strange and some of your scripts will not work properly

Comment: can you provide the script that loads the header/footer and sidebar?

Comment: we are using angular js not php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use URL of *jquery-2.1.4.min.js* file that is defined relatively root of your site. Use started slash to do it.

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

See [Relative URLs](http://webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) article for details.

Comment: how to use js file globally

Comment: if i remove the side in my html file it is working correctly

Comment: @Vinoth, to include global library use CDN (see  answer provided by Abdullah Khan)

Comment: Is there */assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js* exist on your server? Where did you load it from?

Comment: i have tried abdhulla khan answer that also got same error

Comment: @Vinoth, please type absolute URL of the file to a browser address bar. Do you see any text in response?

Comment: i have seen jquery lines

Comment: @Vinoth, hence, your file is available. Thus, you need specify correct URL in `src` attribute in `<script>` tag to fix 404 error. That is URL you type to address bar?

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery UI in addition to simple Jquery library. Date picker is available in Jquery UI. As i do not know the details of your server side, i would recommend using CDN for Jquery library path instead of what you have used.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For old version

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: after i used that jquery i have got 'Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3
'

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? What version of bootstrap are you using? I think you are using an old version. For old version you should use old version of jquery. I have edited my answer. Copy the new link i have given in my answer.